# sound stopped working phonegap media

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

```
$(document).on('click', '#bar img', function () { 



    alphaLetter = $(this).data('club-id');
    audio_file_path = '/android_asset/www/audio/'+alphaLetter+'.mp3';


    var my_media = null;
     my_media = new Media(audio_file_path);

    my_media.play();




    });
```

Above is my code to play sound. It played sound, but when I restarted my project it has stopped working since then, and gives these errors;

```
 E/MediaPlayer(2306): error (-19, 0)
 E/MediaPlayer(2306): Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer
 E/MediaPlayer(2306): error (-38, 0)
 E/MediaPlayer(2306): Error (-19,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by you having too many media objects running at the same time. After the sound is finished you should release it.

The PhoneGap documentation says this about release:

> Function media.release is a synchronous function that releases the
>   underlying operating systems audio resources. This function is
>   particularly important for Android as there are a finite amount of
>   OpenCore instances for media playback. Developers should call the
>   'release' function when they no longer need the Media resource.

I got the same error as well and using reset after finished sounds worked swell for me. Remember to call it after the sound has completed though, such as:

```
var my_media = null;
my_media = new Media(audio_file_path, function()
{
   this.release();
});

my_media.play();
```

I've written more about the problem [here](http://maffelu.net/phonegap-attempt-call-getduration-without-valid-mediaplayer/) if you are interested but the above solution should work well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if this error pops up whenever you try to play the sound even though it is not fully loaded at the certain moment ([Attempt to call getDuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026288/attempt-to-call-getduration-without-a-valid-mediaplayer-in-media-player-on-andr)).

I looked up the Phonegap documentation and couldn't find a method that may check for the availability of the sound. What you can do is:

- Build a Timer that always waits for some time until the sound shall be played.
- Use `var media = new Media(src, mediaSuccess, [mediaError], [mediaStatus]);` for some further handling when playing the sound fails.