# How to catch mediaplayer datasource no file error?

Tags: android, error-handling, media-player, try-catch, android-mediaplayer

I'm having a mediaplayer app where I fetch my datasource from my server with a link path. The problem is when I was testing, I purposely deleted the datasource file of the audio link path I fed to `mp.setDataSource(musicUri);` to check but I can't seem to catch the error and resolve it.

I already replaced my `mp.prepare();` to `mp.prepareAsync();` and simple `mp.start()` to

```
mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
```

to listen if mediaplayer is prepared before starting it.

This is the stack trace:

```
    07-23 13:55:52.492: E/MediaPlayer(6870): Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer
    07-23 13:55:52.492: E/MediaPlayer(6870): error (-38, 0)
    07-23 13:55:52.492: E/MediaPlayer(6870): Error (-38,0)
    07-23 13:55:52.492: E/MediaPlayer(6870): stop called in state 0
    07-23 13:55:52.492: E/MediaPlayer(6870): error (-38, 0)
    07-23 13:55:52.492: E/MediaPlayer(6870): error (1, -107)
```

Nothing seems to work, I would like to catch this error to fix the abnormal results it would cause to the mediaplayer. Any help will do. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Okay, so I added onErrorListener but still not working:

```
mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(musicUri);
        mp.prepareAsync();
        // mp.prepare();
        mp.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(final MediaPlayer mp, final int what,
                    final int extra) {
                Log.e(Constant.TAG_MYREC, "Error occurred while playing audio.");
                mp.stop();
                return false;
            }
        }); 
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp.start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Have you attach an `onErrorListener` to the mediaplayer and does it fire? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html

Comment: @KenWolf I applied an onErrorListener but the error log is still there.

Comment: Where do you call `getDuration`?

Comment: I'll enumerate where it's called, *in my forward button, runnable background thread and onStopTrackingTouch(). And the error is triggered when I play the link path with no mp3 file.

Answer (score 4):

```
mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onError(final MediaPlayer mp, final int what,
            final int extra) {
        Log.e("Error occurred while playing audio.");
        mp.stop();
```

You might be calling getDuration before the file is fully loaded. See if the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710922/android-attempt-to-call-getduration-without-a-valid-mediaplayer) works for you.

Comment: I edited my question. Added onErrorListener but it's not working.

Comment: i've edited the answer check if you find solution for your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple cause of MediaPlayer error, you can check values of `what` and `extra` in `MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.onError`, and do action related to the error cause such as show Toast to notify user.

When file in the Uri is not available, it will return `extra` with value `-1004`, which is according to the docs is `File or network related operation errors`.

Here is another link to Error Codes in MediaType [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html)

The code would be like:

```
@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onError, what: " + what + ", extra: " + extra);

    if (extra == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_IO) {
        // TODO Show Toast
    }


    mp.stop();

    // If you choose not to call onCompletion
    return true;
}
```